# Why is it that, the more '1' bits in my Key, the longer it takes to place in the HashMap?

Tags: java, performance, hashmap, bit, sparse-matrix

I'm doing a project for a class which focuses on storing a huge matrix with mostly 0 values in memory and performing some matrix math on it. My first thought was to use a `HashMap` to store the matrix elements, and only store the elements which are non-zero, in order to avoid using huge quantities of memory.

I wanted to make a key for the `HashMap` which would represent both the row and column number of the element in a way that, when I accessed that entry in the map, I could re-extract both values. I don't know Java as well as C#- in C# I would make a `struct` with `Row` and `Column` members, but in Java I quickly realized there are no User Value Types. With a deadline looming I went with a safe bet and made the `Key` a long. I stored the row data (32-bit int) in the first 32 bits and the column data in the last 32 using some very simple bit shifting. [EDIT: I'd also like to note that my HashMap is initialized with a specific initial size which exactly represents the number of values I store in it, which is never exceeded.]

[Side note: the reason I want to be able to extract the row/column data again is to greatly increase the efficiency of matrix multiplication, from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)`, and a smaller `n` to boot]

What I noticed after implementing this structure is that it takes a whopping 7 seconds to read a 23426 x 23426 matrix from a text file in which only non-zero elements are given, but it only takes 2 seconds to calculate the eigen values we are required to give! After selective commenting-out of methods, I have concluded that the bulk of this 7 second timespan is spent storing my values in the `HashMap`.

```
public void Set(double value, int row, int column) {
    //assemble the long key, placing row and column in adjacent sets of bits
    long key = (long)row << SIZE_BIT_MAX; //(SIZE_BIT_MAX is 32)
    key += column;
    elements.put(key, value);
}
```

That is the code for setting a value. If I use this method instead:

```
public void Set(double value, int row, int column) {
    //create a distinct but smaller key (around 32 bits max)
    long key = (long)(row * matrixSize) + column;
    elements.put(key, value);
}
```

The reading only takes 2 seconds. Both of these versions of the key are distinct for every element, both are long type, and the actual code to create either of them is minimal in complexity. It's the `elements.put(key, value)` which makes the difference between 7 seconds and 2.

My question is, why? The difference I see between these key versions is that the first one has bits set to 1 throughout and more frequently, while the second has all of its highest 32 bits set to 0. Am I chasing a red herring, or is this fairly dramatic difference in performance the result of something internal in the `HashMap.put` method?

Comment: Without an SSCCE, it's pretty hard to tell you the reason. My guess is that you're not specifying an initial size for the map. It then starts out very small and has to resize itself frequently. Resizing, especially for big maps is pretty costly.

Comment: Initial size is specified and never exceeded. I'll edit my post to reflect that.

Comment: Small improvement maybe, but create the HashMap with an appropriate number of initial elements to avoid constantly re-hashing when the new capacity is reached.  for example, new HashMap<Long, Double>(20000);

Comment: Another question is, what is being evaluated by the professor?  Just whether you can do it?  Whether you can implement an efficient sparse matrix algorithm?  If the later, HashMap will probably get you a 'C'.

Comment: See my comment and edit; I caught on to that pretty quickly in the project.

Comment: brettw- why so? The purpose of the project is to balance memory usage and computation efficiency on very large sparse matrices. The professor's guidelines are frustratingly vague, but the grading seems to be based on both the memory usage and efficiency of the algorithms. Of all the data structures I've seen implemented for this project by my peers, though, the HashMap seems to win for both. Is there something I'm not aware of? [edit: maybe I should have read Wikipedia!]

Comment: I'd also note that the matrix is never altered after initial load. The elements don't have to be iterated over in sorted order, either. I'm not sure how much that mitigates the inferiority of the HashMap.

Comment: I just tried the List Of Lists method and ran out of heap memory. I doubt I've fully optimized, but the program had already been running for longer than the HashMap implementation when the exception was thrown. I think for the sake of getting sleep tonight and having this project done with, I'll stick with what I know works fairly well for the project's requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at how `Long` implements the `hashCode()` method (at least in OpenJDK 7):

```
public int hashCode() {
    return (int)(value ^ (value >>> 32));
}
```

This means that your key gets stuffed back into 32 bits; all the lower bits are cancelling each other out quite often, resulting in a lot of collisions which requires the `HashMap` to spend extra time looking for a free slot in a bucket. Your second method avoids that problem because every key’s generated hash code is a unique value (because you only have 23426 x 23426 = 548777476 items which fits well into 32 bits).

So, the resaon is your key selection but not the number of set bits.

However, what exactly do you mean with “user value types?”

```
public class MatrixKey {
    private final int row;
    private final int column;
    public MatrixKey(int row, int column) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
    }
    public int getRow() { return row; }
    public int getColumn() { return column; }
}
```

This class can make a perfectly good key for a `Map` in Java once you implement `hashCode()` and `equals()`. Just make sure that you don’t implement its `hashCode` method the way `Long` does. :)

Comment: +1, but to use this as a map key, you should implement hashcode and equals. Otherwise, you won't be able to retrieve anything from the map...

Comment: I think I just don't know enough Java, but I wasn't aware of a value type like the Struct in C# which uses bitwise equality instead of reference equality or defined hashes. My main impetus in using an Integer or Long for my key was to take advantage of Java's pre-implemented unique hashes instead of writing my own, because I basically suck at that and I didn't want to waste time on the project figuring it out.

Comment: @jackrabbit: What do you mean by "Otherwise, you won't be able to retrieve anything from the map" ? Agreed that implementing `hashCode` and `equals` is strongly recommended, but `MatrixKey` shall use Object class implementation for lookup right if it does not have these behaviors defined?

Comment: Java doesn't implement unique hashes.  In fact, "unique hash" is an oxymoron - a contradiction in terms.

Comment: What I meant was distinct hashes for distinct objects. Or, what I really mean is, when I write hashes they tend to end up being the same for objects which are not equal. Granted, I haven't tried to write a hash function in a while, but I didn't want to give it another go on a deadline.

Comment: @darkie15 The default equals and hashcode implementation don't look at the content of an object. Object.equals performs a reference equality check: an object is only equal to itself. As a result, if you create two MatrixKey instances with the same parameters, they will still not be equal to each other. The default hashcode is consistent with the default equals implementation, not looking at any of the object's state.

Answer (score 3):

From the [JDK 6 documentation for `Long.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#hashCode()) (note that your `long` primitive is autoboxed into a `Long` object - whereas in C# primitives actually *are* objects):

> Returns a hash code for this Long. The result is the exclusive OR of the two halves of the primitive long value held by this Long object. That is, the hashcode is the value of the expression:
>
> ```
> (int)(this.longValue()^(this.longValue()>>>32))
> ```

I think given this definition, this explains why:

<strike>the collision rate is reduced when you introduce more entropy and thus disperse it more via the upper half of the `long` value.</strike> (**edit**: I read the order wrong, so here's the counter-argument below)

The collisions might be more likely when extending into the `long` range - after all, in Java, hashCodes are only `int` size, so you can only have a limited amount of equal distribution. If you know it's "evenly" distributed over an `int` range then your collisions are reduced. If you spread that out across the `long` range, then it greatly increases your chance of collision.

Here's [from the `HashMap` Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) (emphasis mine):

> This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put), **assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets**

Side note: you'll find even greater performance gains by tuning the `initial capacity` and `load factor` - check the `HashMap` documentation for more information.

Comment: I think the OP is observing the exact opposite. When the upper-half is all zeros, it's faster.

Comment: Oh, whoops, good catch. I'll edit my response with a different approach.

Comment: Looks like Bombe stole this from you while you were editing! Oh well, they're both good explanations for some of the internal workings of Long and HashMap in Java. Thanks for responding! I'd mark you both as correct but that's not allowed...

Comment: Well, I got it completely opposite to begin with, so he should get the points :)

Comment: “If you know it's "evenly" distributed over an `int` range then it's definitely not going to collide” — sorry but that is just plain wrong. Collisions are only minimized; you can very well get a hash code collision with only two elements in a map.

Comment: @Bombe Whoops, good point - another misunderstanding on my part. Hopefully my edited statement is more accurate. Technically I could have been correct if the hashmap is initialized to the size `Integer.MAX_VALUE` size, though.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the implementation, you could be hitting hash collisions.

If all of your hash values end up in the same "bucket", the implementation will normally throw them onto a list of some type. If this is the case your access times will suffer significantly.

Comment: Access times don't seem to be any different, though, unless you're talking about accessing existing values in the map when a new value is inserted to check equality.